# Function prob: expected unqualified-id before '[' token

Tags: c++, constexpr

I get an undescriptive error: expected unqualified-id before '[' token. Naturally, because this is not Java or C#, I have no clue what's going on.

Here's my code:

```
constexpr GLfloat[NUM_VERTS * ELEM_PER_NORM] GetNormals(bool normalize)
{
    glm::vec3 normal = glm::vec3(1.f, 1.f, 1.f);

    if (normalize)
        normal = glm::normalize(normal);

    return {-normal.x, -normal.y, -normal.z, // Back
            -normal.x, normal.y, -normal.z,
            normal.x, normal.y, -normal.z,
            normal.x, -normal.y, -normal.z,

            -normal.x, -normal.y, normal.z, // Front
            -normal.x, normal.y, normal.z,
            normal.x, normal.y, normal.z,
            normal.x, -normal.y, normal.z};
}
```

I also get two other errors: "expected '}' at end of input" and "expected unqualified-id at end of input". Those two send me to my source .cpp instead of my header source where my previous code is. It sends my to a function without mistakes ( void DrawBuffers::InitVboIbo(){} ).

Thank you! :)

EDIT:

Here's my new code:

```
constexpr std::array<GLfloat, NUM_VERTS * ELEM_PER_NORM> GetNormals(bool normalize)
{
    glm::vec3 normal = glm::vec3(1.f, 1.f, 1.f);

    if (normalize)
        normal = glm::normalize(normal);

    std::array<GLfloat, NUM_VERTS * ELEM_PER_NORM> res =
          {{-normal.x, -normal.y, -normal.z, // Back
            -normal.x, normal.y, -normal.z,
            normal.x, normal.y, -normal.z,
            normal.x, -normal.y, -normal.z,

            -normal.x, -normal.y, normal.z, // Front
            -normal.x, normal.y, normal.z,
            normal.x, normal.y, normal.z,
            normal.x, -normal.y, normal.z}};

    return res;
}

const static GLfloat normals[NUM_VERTS * ELEM_PER_NORM] = GetNormals(true);
```

Comment: You cannot return an array, only a pointer

Comment: @awesomeyi: Or an array embedded in a class, like `std::array`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to return an array from a constexpr function you should use `std::array` like `std::array<GLfloat, NUM_VERTS * ELEM_PER_NORM>`. You cannot return `std::vector` because it has non-constexpr constructor, you cannot return pointers to a local arrays because they get destroyed, you cannot create static const array because it must differ based on function parameter.

Comment: Also, shouldn't constexpr functions be one-liners containing a single return statement?

Comment: @JorenHeit In C++14 they shouldn't. Clang, gcc and msvc 2013 CTP support such syntax.

Comment: And I thought I was being progressive by using C++11 features. Will look into C++14 soon...

Comment: Ok I tried with std::array but I have difficulties with constexpr. If I put const static instead of constexpr, gcc is unhappy and send me an error because he wants me to use constexpr (but I get no other errors). If I keep constexpr, it tells me that I can't call my function without object. What does it mean "without object"? I also get those two errors:

Comment: 'constexpr' needed for in-class initialization of static data member 'const GLfloat DrawBuffers::normals [24]' of non-integral type [-fpermissive]
error: body of constexpr function 'constexpr std::array<float, 24u> DrawBuffers::GetNormals(bool) const' not a return-statement|

Comment: @user2924010 In c++11 constexpr functions  must consist of only `return ...` statement. It was relaxed only in c++14, and unfortunately gcc does not support it yet. You may try clang instead.

Comment: But why can't I use a const static function? Why does the compiler don't let me use a const static function when I could use a constexpr function?

Comment: @user2924010 Because you're using it to initialize static const variable in a global scope I suppose. Their content must be known at compile-time, thus you must use constexpr function to do it.